# Sort bibliography alphabetically when 1st author is the same using the plainnat bibliography style

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, sorting

I have a lot of articles writed by Lionel Ho and co-workers. I use `natbib` package and `plainnat` style. When I compile, the bibliography is not sorted by the last name of the second author. How can I solve it?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[comma,authoryear,round,sort]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\setcitestyle{citesep={;},yysep={;}}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Ho2012,
  author   = {Ho, Lionel and Dreyfus, J. and Boyer, J. and Lowe, T. and Bustamante, H. and Duker, P. and Meli, T. and Newcombe, G.},
  title    = {Fate of...},
  year     = {2012},
}

@Article{Ho2007,
  author   = {Ho, Lionel and Hoefel, D. and Saint, C. P. and Newcombe, Gayle},
  title    = {Isolation...},
  year     = {2007},}

@Article{Ho2008,
  author  = {Ho, Lionel and Slyman, Najwa and Kaeding, Uwe and Newcombe, Gayle},
  title   = {Optimizing...},
  year    = {2008},}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document} 
\citep{Ho2012,Ho2007,Ho2008}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

I tried erasing the `sort` option

```
\usepackage[comma,authoryear,round]{natbib}
```

but the result is the same

Comment: The scheme is author-year, so it first sorts by first author, then by year, so the sorting is correct.

Comment: @HenriMenke Right, but it's impossible to sort by allthe authors first and then by year?

Comment: It's not impossible but it doesn't make sense either.

Comment: `plainnat` is "special" in that it sorts only on the first-placed author's surname, not on *all* authors' surnames. Other bibliography styles have other sorting criteria. You may want to look into running the `makebst` utility of the `custom-bib` package to create a bespoke bib style file that incorporates all of your formatting requirements. The utility is menu-driven; the output of a run is the bst file.

Comment: @HenriMenke - Various other authoryear-based bibtex style files *do* sort by all authors' surnames, not just the first author's surname. `plainnat`'s sorting habits are certainly not universal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick fix to your issue might go along the lines of the following code:

```
% start of bib file
@preamble{ " \providecommand{\noopsort[1]{}} " }
@Article{Ho2012,
  author   = {Ho, Lionel and Dreyfus, J. and Boyer, J. and Lowe, T. and Bustamante, H. and Duker, P. and Meli, T. and Newcombe, G.},
  title    = {Fate of...},
  year     = {\noopsort{c}2012},}
@Article{Ho2007,
  author   = {Ho, Lionel and Hoefel, D. and Saint, C. P. and Newcombe, Gayle},
  title    = {Isolation...},
  year     = {\noopsort{a}2007},}
@Article{Ho2008,
  author  = {Ho, Lionel and Slyman, Najwa and Kaeding, Uwe and Newcombe, Gayle},
  title   = {Optimizing...},
  year    = {\noopsort{b}2008},}
% bib file continues...
```

The `\noopsort` macro does nothing, as far as LaTeX is concerned, but it plays a role during BibTeX's operations. Basically, BibTeX "sees" 3 entries, with year fields given by "a2007", "b2008", and "c2012"; guess how they get sorted. The "a", "b", and "c" particles "disappear" during subsequent processing by LaTeX.

---

A more thorough fix, to ensure that sorting is performed automatically according to all authors' surnames, involves modifying (a copy of) the file `plainnat.bst`. I suggest you proceed as follows:

- Find the files `plainnat.bst` and `chicago.bst` in your TeX distribution. (Why `chicago.bst`, you might ask? It's because it's a bib style that happens to perform sorting based on all authors' surnames.) Make a copy of `plainnat.bst` and call the copy, say `plainnat-mod.bst`. *Do not edit an original file of the TeX distribution directly.*
- Open the files `plainnat-mod.bst` and `chicago.bst` in a text editor. The program you use to edit your tex files will do fine.
- In the files `plainnat-mod.bst` and `chicago.bst`, locate the function called `sort.format.names`. (In my copies of these files, the function starts on line 1207 and line 1407, respectively.)
- In the file `plainnat-mod.bst`, delete all 29 lines (1207 thru 1235) of the function `sort.format.names`. Copy and paste all 21 lines (1407 thru 1427) from the function `sort.format.names` in `chicago.bst` to the place in `plainnat-mod.bst` where you just deleted a bunch of lines.
- Close the file `chicago.bst`, and save and close the file `plainnat-mod.bst`. Save the latter file either in the directory where your main tex file is located or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter option, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution appropriately.
- In your main tex file, change the instruction `\bibliographystyle{plainnat-mod}` to `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}`. Then, perform a full recompile cycle (latex, bibtex, and latex twice more) to fully propagate all changes.

Happy BibTeXing!